# Prolog list has uninstantiated tail, need to get rid of it

Tags: list, prolog

I'm working on a Prolog program. It produces the correct output (a list) but the list has an uninstantiated variable at the end. I am doing something wrong, and am unsure how to get rid of it.

This is the code:

```prolog
plaatsingen([],_).
plaatsingen([Prod/Hoev|Rest],[Order|Plaatsing]) :-
    prijs(Lev,Prod,Prijs),
    Kost is Prijs*Hoev,
    Order = Lev/Prod/Kost,
    plaatsingen(Rest,Plaatsing).

prijs(delhaize, zeep, 8).
prijs(delhaize, prei, 10).
prijs(delhaize, zout, 6).
prijs(carrefour, prei, 9).
prijs(carrefour, soep, 19).
prijs(champion, zeep, 7).
prijs(champion, prei, 11).
prijs(champion, pinda, 6).
```

This is the input and output:

```prolog
    41 ?- plaatsingen([zeep/10, prei/14],P).
P = [delhaize/zeep/80, delhaize/prei/140|_G4160] .
```

Comment: The problem is that the base case (first clause) for `plaatsingen` has `_` as its second parameter.

Comment: something like [_|[]] in place of _ doesn't work however. (Trying to unify the variable with the empty list)

Comment: What's wrong with `plaatsingen([], []).`? The parameter doesn't represent a list of lists. It represents a list. You have to think about what that clause represents: it is establishing the relationship of `plaatsingen` for an empty list is an empty list.

Comment: leaving last list argument uninstantiated can lead to difference lists, but also to some bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get rid of it, you need to get a handle on it:

```
plaatsingen([],G,G).
plaatsingen([Prod/Hoev|Rest],[Order|Plaatsing],G) :-
    prijs(Lev,Prod,Prijs),
    Kost is Prijs*Hoev,
    Order = Lev/Prod/Kost,
    plaatsingen(Rest,Plaatsing,G).
```

`G` is such a handle. Now you get back in it the uninstantiated tail, explicitly, and can set it to anything:

```
plaatsingen(In, Out, Z), Z=[].
```

sets the end of list to the empty list. Or you can pre-set it, with

```
plaatsingen(In, Out, [end, of, list]).
```

or leave it as a free logvar, which is the mechanism of *difference lists*.

Comment: Why this unnecessary complication of using a difference list?  You should at least explain the straightforward fix first...

Comment: @jschimpf I don't see it as complication, but rather as explication. That it is a difference list is merely a coincidence. :) Feel free to add your own answer, it's always good to have several points of view...

Comment: @jschimpf but mainly, because it was [already shown in the comments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20838760/prolog-list-has-uninstantiated-tail-need-to-get-rid-of-it/20842235#comment31256819_20838760).

Answer (score 0):

when facing a list processing problem, try to see if a Prolog [builtin](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=apply) can help:

```
plaatsingen(I, Orders) :-
    maplist(plaatsingen_c, I, Orders).

plaatsingen_c(Prod/Hoev, Lev/Prod/Kost) :-
    prijs(Lev,Prod,Prijs),
    Kost is Prijs*Hoev.
```

yields

```
3 ?- plaatsingen([zeep/10, prei/14],P).
P = [delhaize/zeep/80, delhaize/prei/140] ;
P = [delhaize/zeep/80, carrefour/prei/126] 
...
```

easier, isn't it ? For more complex processing, see '[all solutions](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=allsolutions)' and [aggregation](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=aggregate)